# rosserial_arduino IDE ARDUINO error

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i'm workin' with the Arduino target, i installed the Arduino IDE , and also installed rosserial_arduino and put the ros_lib on the sketchbook file. i try to run , i mean compile the examples, in these case the blink example and i got these error:

```
Blink.pde:-1: error: ‘ros’ has not been declared
Blink.pde:-1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘nh’
Blink.pde:-1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘::’ token
Blink.pde:-1: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘std_msgs’ with no type
Blink.pde:-1: error: ‘ros’ has not been declared
Blink.pde:-1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
Blink.cpp: In function ‘void setup()’:
Blink.pde:-1: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
Blink.pde:-1: error: ‘sub’ was not declared in this scope
Blink.cpp: In function ‘void loop()’:
Blink.pde:-1: error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
```

thnks for any help i can get

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68692/rosserial_arduino-ide-arduino-error/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros_lib needs to be in the /libraries folder of the sketchbook folder.  Did you put it there?  Seems like it may not be seeing ros.h
If you try to import the library from the arduino IDE menu, does the ros_lib folder show up in the list?  If not, then it is not in the correct location.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0